# sails js data relationship

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Does sails.js support relationships between models/collections? If so, can someone point to documentation?

For example: I have 2 models

1.Production

```
production: {
  name: 'string',
  description: 'text'
}
```

2.Album

```
album: {
  name: 'string',
  productionID: 'ObjectID'// How do I get to "production"?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sailsjs `0.9.x` does not support relationships or associations currently. `0.10` does have a rough outline of this working.

**Disclaimer:** the `0.10` branch is a constant work in progress and can break on a daily basis as the contributors push code to it, if somethings broken its best to ask in the irc #sailsjs chat or post an issue tagged 0.10 if it truly is broken.

You can install sailsjs v0.10 to give it a try by doing something like the following.. (I'm not in front of my machine to test this but it should work).

```
   #in your downloads directory or somewhere globally accessible clone the 0.10 branch
   git clone https://github.com/balderdashy/sails -b v0.10 sails;
   cd sails; npm install; npm link;
   #this will install all sails dependencies, and npm link sails to that cloned folder
```

Once its installed you can then run `sails -v` and you should get `0.10`.

Then its just a matter of generating a new sails app with `sails new <appname>`

Answer (score 0):

Waterline, the ORM for Sails, does support associations between models/collections.  However, support for associations is a work in progress.  With that being said, the MySQL and Postgresql support is the furthest along.

You may find the unfinished documentation for waterline v0.10 here:

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs