# Building one page apps with angularjs and sails.js backend

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sails.js

I just found out about sails.js and i think it's really awesome. I want to build apps with sails and angular, but i haven't found any guides on doing this. I found this [site](http://phillydotnet.org/sessions/the-new-means-stack-with-sails-js-mongodbexpressangularjsnode-jssails-js/) which is supposed to have a talk on using sails.js instead on express in the mean stack, but there's not video there.
I would be glad for links to videos or blog posts on how to do this.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is getting downvoted because its not a direct question about code.

I have a boilerplate sailsjs app that you can use to model your own off of..

https://github.com/mikedevita/sailsjs-v10-angularjs-requirejs-boilerplate

This is based on v0.10 which is in beta right now, but the same concept applies.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run your app to see how it works, but i had problems with the grunt not finding the watch task, how can i get it to work? Thanks agin

Comment: most likely you need to install sailsjs v0.10.. see my answer on this question for how to do that.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366618/sails-js-data-relationship/21366730#21366730

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it worked for me.
Another thing. I realised that grunt can't find the various tasks because of the path 
    var depsPath = grunt.option('gdsrc') || 'node_modules/sails/node_modules';
making it var depsPath = grunt.option('gdsrc') || "node_modules" made it work
any comments on that?
Thanks again.

PS: Though it works, i get this error (when i run grunt)
Running "coffee:dev" (coffee) task
Warning: Task "sails-linker:devJs" not found. Use --force to continue.

Comment: Sails has dependencies which are indeed located in `node_nodules/sails/node_modules` and those dependencies i think are grunt related tasks as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a simple yet powerful angular service, published as a bower component: https://github.com/diegopamio/angular-sails-bind

It basically:

- Creates the model inside the $scope for you.
- Retrieves the model data from the backend using socket.
- Watches for changes made by the user in the UI and updates the backend immediately.
- Watches for changes made in the backend and updates the UI immediately.

And it does it with just one line of code in your angular app, like this:  $sailsBind("", $scope);

I made it as part of a personal project and then I decided to publish it as it could benefit others. It works with sails 0.10. Let me know if it suits your needs or if you'd like to see something else on it.